# IBM WebSphere Commerce Promotions

Tags: ip-address, commerce, promotions, websphere-commerce

I'm pretty new to WebSphere Commerce and I had a question regarding Promotions. I know you can set Promotions to be only accessible by a certain group of users and what not. But how do you go about editing this and is it possible to restrict promotions by IP Address (for region lock purposes). Any information on this would be helpful!

Answer (score 1):

I am not deep-technical but I work in the WebSphere Commerce space at IBM. A good start is the InfoCenter for WebSphere Commerce. Promotions are covered here,  http://pic.dhe.ibm.com/infocenter/wchelp/v7r0m0/topic/com.ibm.commerce.management-center.doc/concepts/cprover.htm

In case you are working for a company who owns WebSphere Commerce software I would also recommend to get in contact with IBM Support. They usually can help very well.

Personally I am not sure if IP address is a good way to restrict promotions. Simply imagine *company* in Germany is using a IP addresses in UK as gateway to the internet and no German sees German promotions while visiting your website at work desk. Would a browser language setting says much more about the user (US-English, UK-English, German, French, Spanish, Arabic, etc)?

Answer (score 0):

You can edit the promotions created by directly editing the database tables.
Please refer IBM info center here for the data model[Promotion data model](http://pic.dhe.ibm.com/infocenter/wchelp/v6r0m0/topic/com.ibm.commerce.data.doc/refs/rdmpromo.htm)

Comment: I would not edit the database tables directly.   This would violate the business rules in the business logic layer.

Answer (score 0):

For region locking, we tend to recommend using a business rule in the order management component (very common in scenarios selling to countries on the restricted state dept list).

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve it with the following way -

1. Create a new promotion type.
2. Within the Promotion implementation class put the restriction to apply the reward only after checking the Customer's IP.

The only problem with this strategy is that Promotion will get triggered as soon as the condition is met irrespective of users IP and you will have to restrict application of reward later.

For example -

Create a Promotion type Buy X Get Y free and associate a new implementation class CustomPromotionBuyXGetY. Within this class apply the reward only after verifying the customer location.

Following articles might be of help -

http://pic.dhe.ibm.com/infocenter/wchelp/v6r0m0/index.jsp?topic=%2Fcom.ibm.commerce.management-center_customization.doc%2Ftutorial%2Ftpr_index.htm